# How to get 6 positions (x,y,z) so that they form a circle around a custom position oriented away from the origin?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code a 3D model of a tree-like structure in Unity. The idea is to have a fully generative stylized tree for an AR project I'm working on. Once the vertices for the main trunk are created I need to draw vertices almost perpendicular to it at certain points, I have the first points drawn at the right position, but the orientation is wrong.

So far I have the vertices being drawn in the correct position using :

```
     float nrad = (float)nodule_vertices / nbSides * _2pi;
     Vector3 GOpos = new Vector3(pos.x + Mathf.Cos(nrad) * bottomRadius * 0.8f, pos.y + Mathf.Cos(nrad) * bottomRadius * 0.8f, pos.z + Mathf.Sin(nrad) * bottomRadius * 0.8f);
```

However, this just gives me a skewed circle of vertices around the given position, not in the correct orientation.

[Vertices represented by Spheres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2lK6.png)

I've placed some spheres to show the vertices, I need to fix the orientation of this group.

What I'm trying to achieve is how to have the circle of vertices angled to be perpendicular to the main trunk.

Comment: What is the trunk direction? The vertices should be located in a plane orthogonal to the trunk.

Comment: The trunk is pretty much following y+ with some deformations along the way, but since the placement of the branches is randomised, I'm having trouble figuring out the x and z direction of their orientation.

Comment: I added a screenshot, might help understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured this one out so for anyone with a similar problem here goes.

Assuming that the main trunk is rooted in the centre of the world (0,0,0), the closer a vertex is to an axis the more deformation it should get along that axis. So for example, a circle with a center point where X is 0, should have the maximum deformation along the X axis, and the minimum deformation along the Z axis. However, should the center point be at the furthest point from the center of the trunk (X being the radius of the trunk), it should get the minimum deformation along the X axis and maximum along the Z.

To do this I used Mathf.InverseLerp to assign a percentage of modification along the X and Z axis separately.

The following code still needs some cleanup but gets us close.

```
Vector3 GOpos = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(pos.x + Mathf.Sin(nrad)*Mathf.InverseLerp(bottomRadius, 0.0f, Mathf.Abs(pos.x)), pos.x-bottomRadius/2, pos.x+bottomRadius/2), pos.y + Mathf.Cos(nrad) * bottomRadius, Mathf.Clamp(pos.z + Mathf.Sin(nrad) * Mathf.InverseLerp(bottomRadius, 0.0f, Mathf.Abs(pos.z)), pos.z-bottomRadius/2, pos.z+bottomRadius/2));
```